# What is the proper noun for the guy sitting beside truck driver?

Tags: nouns

I cannot find the proper noun for the guy who is accompanying the truck driver throughout the journey?Is he considered a truck driver? His responsibility is to drive the truck when the main driver is tired or sleepy.

Also, is there a website or a book that has collection of such jargon?

Comment: I spent a summer as a driver's mate, but that may just be UK usage.

Comment: "Team drivers" are both CDL drivers. In electronic log books, one is active (driving) and the other inactive/sleep mode. No doubt, truckers have their own lingo. Also saw "co-driver". https://www.smart-trucking.com/team-truck-driving/

Comment: Sometimes it’s just *her husband*.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*co-driver*

See, for example, https://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/S2093791118301070

Whether the truck driver or the co-driver is in charge,  or whether they share responsibility,I don’t know. My guess is that one of two drivers makes final decisions about who drives when.

Answer (score 1):

Handyman: In India, the one who sits beside a truck driver whose responsibility is to assist the driver in driving with a proper nevigation that helps the driver keeping his driving safe is called a handyman.  While, If both are drivers having the same responsibilities and drive alternatively then they may be simply called co- drivers.

Comment: In India, the one sitting beside the driver was popularly known as cleaner, because his duty was mainly to clean the vehicle, occupy driver's seat occasionally to be groomed into a better driver (often without a driving licence). This is specially for trucks.  These days, for inter-state overnight journey high-tech buses have two drivers; and they are co-drivers. I am not sure of a globally accepted word for it.